# Restcomm USSD Gateway on Wildfly or JBoss EAP 7

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, ussd, restcomm

I'm new to Restcomm USSD Gateway, and I am doing some tests on it. I get it to work with bootstrapped JBoss 5.1 , but I was wondering if it's possible, with some effort, to make it to work with the newest JBoss EAP/Wildfly and Java versions. Anyone knows if it's possible, or there are restrictions due the versions?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Restcomm USSD Gateway is based on [JAIN SLEE](https://github.com/RestComm/jain-slee) we are working hard to release a new version JAIN SLEE that is based on Wildfly 10.1 and EAP 7. We will then update USSD Gateway to it. It should be available in Q2 of this year.